# GetAsync from Recipients Object behaves differently between Outlook and OWA

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

After testing with different versions of outlook and also different platforms. We noticed that the GetAsync method of the object "Office.context.mailbox.item.to" acts differently between platforms.

When writing an email address on OWA, the callback from the GetAsync will be called by pressing "Tab" or ";" or when the focus has changed. It's what we expect and we can then do some validations/modifications with this array of email addresses.

However with Outlook 2016 MSO, the callback won't be called when the ";" is pressed. It means that when an user writes an email address and click on "send" straight after, our validation/modification won't be made.

Do you have any idea how to get this event on Outlook ? Is there any version compatibilities to take into consideration ? Is this "behaviour" known ? Are there some workaround ?

In the documentation (Office.recipients) it says "When the call completes, the asyncResult.value property will contain an array of Office.EmailAddressDetails objects.". But we don't have a good idea what "the call completes" is meant.

Greetings,
Davy

Comment: to.getAsync isn't an event. The callback should return immediately when you call it. In your add-in, when you call the function it will return to you every *resolved* recipient in the field. It's not an event. The callback will be called back ONCE for each time you make the call. (maybe you can share your code to help).Are you instead talking about how each client resolves recipients? Otherwise I think there may be some confusion here about what the "callback" is.

Comment: Hello, we create an issue with my colleague: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532295/item-to-getasync-when-the-to-value-changed-is-trigerred-to-late